# Mostrar datos en forma de cuadrícula ionic 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, ionic2

Recibo datos de un REST Api cuando abro una pantalla específica y debo presentar esos datos en forma de cuadrícula. Ahora los estoy presentando en una lista y todo correcto (este es el código)

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let pais of paises">
  <ion-thumbnail style="max-width: 300px !important;" item-left>
      <img [src]="pais.url_bandera" />
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2 [innerHTML] = "pais.nombre"></h2>
  <span [innerHTML] = "pais.datos_generales"></span>
</ion-item>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es que en vez de presentarlo como una lista, necesito presentarlo como una cuadrícula en donde entren 2 paises por fila. Algo parecido a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has probado con `<ion-row><ion-col>`?

Comment: Sé que se puede hacer con eso. El problema es cómo. No sé me viene ninguna idea. Por eso puse el código, porque no sé manejar bien angular.

Comment: Como consejo, en la informatica es muy importante probar, intentar, asi todo el rato.  y es cuando te tiras de los pelos cuando se pregunta en sitios como este. si no te peleas con el problema no avanzarás. Además, despues de luchar, si lo consigues, es una gran satisfaccion ^^